# System Indicator icon, what does it mean?

Tags: system

What does it mean when the system indicator icon (red triangle with a white exclamation point in the center) shows up next to the phone number I sent a text to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon means the text is not sent. Just click on that text and it will push the typed text into compose box, you just have to press send.